# Crystal Reports prompting for Login Credentials on Client Application, even with credentials being passed in cod

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, .net-4.8

Regardless of how I handle this, Crystal is asking for login creds on the client.  It works as intended on dev machines.   Not sure what is causing the issue.   The Dev Machines are Win 10, whereas the client is Server 2019.    I've installed the x64 Crystal Runtimes and .Net 4.8 on 2019.    The app otherwise works fine.   Just prompts for login creds when I preview Crystal Reports.  Here is my code:

```
    private void generateReport()
{
    string studyNum = txtStudyNum.Text.Trim().ToString();
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    Tables CrTables;

    var appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string reportName = "SponserSearch.rpt";
    var relativePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("StudyManagement", "Reports", reportName);
    appPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, relativePath);

    // System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(appPath.ToString()); 

    cryRpt.Load(appPath);  //path to report

    crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Properties.Settings.Default.strDBServer;
    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Properties.Settings.Default.strDBName;
    crConnectionInfo.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.strDBUser;
    crConnectionInfo.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.strDBPass;
    crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
    

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
    {
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
    }

    cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon(Properties.Settings.Default.strDBUser, Properties.Settings.Default.strDBPass);
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@SponsorInfo", studyNum);
    crystalViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cryRpt;
}
```

Couples things I've noticed.
The reports that aren't working are using SQLNCI11 The native sql client 11.  The reports are fine but prompts for login.

MS recommended replacing the Provider with MSOLEDBSQL, but it works just like the SQLNCI11 provider.

The SQLOLEDB Provider does not prompt for Credentials, but the Crystal Date fields coming in from SQL are all strings.   Which really creates a major headache and break 100+ reports.

I've also, tried to remove the login aspect and move to Integrated Security. It still prompts for login credentials.

Comment: I _just_ finished dealing with a very similar issue. When the report is failing, are you by chance attempting to set credentials using the same `ServerName` and `DatabaseName` values that are present at design time? Our issue only presented when doing that, but we use integrated security. If we changed either `ServerName` or `DatabaseName` to differ from what is stored in the report it worked.

Comment: Also, did your server get a patch/reboot earlier this week? Our problem first presented on Wednesday after we had a "Patch Tuesday" and reboot the previous morning.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to continue using the SQL Native Client 11, and just install the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065